Problem in aggregation st_union
Recently we migrated our geodatabase from Oracle to Aurora PostgreSQL RDS.
Earlier on Oracle we were aggregating geometries using the ST_Union function. But on RDS it is not working as expected or in same way like before.
This data get used by ArcGIS Pro tool and many of the geometries showing invalid or rejected by tool.
We tried following function
st_union, st_make_valid, st_buffer, st_Simplfy etc, But no luck. How can I fix this issue?

Please provide examples of source geometries and explain what you have done for them. But I guess that the difference may in certain kind of polygons, see self-touching rings in https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValidDetail.html. ESRI seems to have some methods for ESRI and OGC validation https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/repair-geometry.htm.

I tried multiple options starting from st_union. Problem is ST_IsValidDetail and ST_IsValid show it as Valid but it fails in ArcGis tool. How can I share this data? Each record is very big in size. Suggest me how you would like to see.

Did you use ST_IsValidDetail with the ESRI flag?

Yes! I did used ST_IsValidDetail and for each record I am getting (t,,). I think which means it is valid but in ArcGis it is dropping record or saying invalid geometry.

Please confirm that you used ST_IsValidDetail with the ESRI flag this way:  ST_IsValidDetail(geom,1). The 1 is the flag. The flag is optional and it is 0 by default, and thus the validity is checked by the OGC rules if the flag is not set, or when it is set to 0.

Yes, I tried both the way with value(ST_IsValidDetail(geom,1)) and without value(ST_IsValidDetail(geom)) both the time it is giving same output (t,,)

Ok, that route was a dead end. I cannot guess what else it could be without test data that could be used for re-producing the error.

But again How can I give you this data? I don't see way to attach anything here.

By using some file sharing service. But I do not promise anything, I give answers here for fun and for me ArcGIS is not fun really.

It's curious that you haven't attempted to use ArcGIS tools to diagnose the problem (Check Geometry). If you can't generate a representative sample here, we can't help. Esri Tech Support. will need data as well.

It's curious that you haven't attempted to use ArcGIS tools to diagnose (Check Geometry) or fix (Repair Geometry) the problem . If you can't generate a representative sample here, we can't help. Esri Tech Support would need data as well.

I tried repair geometry in ArcGis Pro tol and getting error like following
Repaired feature objectid: 187 because of a structural error! (-155) Linestring or poly boundary is self-intersecting
Repaired feature objectid: 192 because of a structural error! (-151) A polygon outer shell does not completely enclose all donuts for the part
